# How to enable the tell me what you want to do search box in Ms Office Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am unable to enable the "tell me what you want to do" search box in Ms Office Excel 2016

Comment: depending on your screen resolution you have it may be pushed off of the ribbon to the right.

Comment: The screen is 15.6" and the resolution is 1920 x 1080. I have now noted that a search box similar to the "Tell me what" is appearing on the quick access tool bar instead of the ribbon.